# Combining Input from STDIN and File in Perl

Tags: perl, file, file-handling

I want to have my Perl script to be able to do this

```
./code1 param1 param2 param3 | perl myperlscript.pl param1 param2
```

So the Perl script ought to take 3 inputs:

1. param1
2. param2
3. output of   `./code1 param1 param2 param3`

I have this in my Perl code but it goes awry:

```
my $param1 = $ARGV[0] || "control.fst";
my $param2  = $ARGV[1] || "target.fst";

my @control_header = `grep ">" $param1`;
my @target_header = `grep ">" $param2`;
# Later to do something with those arrays

while (<>) {
 # do something again
}
```

I am aware I can make temporary output for `./code1`.
But since the output is quite large I prefer to have it piped.
Please advice what's the right way to do it.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *goes awry*. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More ***perlish*** code would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $param1 = $ARGV[0] || "control.fst";
my $param2 = $ARGV[1] || "target.fst";

my @control_header;
my @target_header;

open FH, "<$param1" or die;
map { push @control_header, $1 if /^(.*?>.*?)[\n\r]*$/ } (<FH>);
close FH;

open FH, "<$param2" or die;
map { push @target_header,  $1 if /^(.*?>.*?)[\n\r]*$/ } (<FH>);
close FH;

...                                                                              

while (<STDIN>) {                                                                
  ...                                                                            
}
```

Comment: Optionally you can extend `die` output and replace `die;` with  `die "Cannot open file $param1";` or  similar...

Comment: map in void context isn't very perish at all.

Comment: You really shouldn't encourage using *typeglob* file handles or the two-parameter form of `open`. Also the `die` string should contain `$!` for information.

Answer (score 4):

While `@ARGV` isn't empty the `<>` operator will read from the files specified there. Reading continues from `STDIN` once `@ARGV` is exhausted.

If you empty `@ARGV` explicitly after you have read the `@control_header` and `@target_header` arrays the program should work as you expect. Alternatively you can read explicitly from `STDIN` using `<STDIN>`.

But I believe it is better to use Perl to read the information you need from the file parameters. This program demonstrates the idea

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $param1 = shift || 'control.fst';
my @control_header = do {
  open my $fh, '<', $param1 or die qq(Unable to open file "$param1": $!);
  grep />/, <$fh>;
};

my $param2 = shift || 'target.fst';
my @target_header = do {
  open my $fh, '<', $param2 or die qq(Unable to open file "$param2": $!);
  grep />/, <$fh>;
};

while (<STDIN>) {
  # do something again
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case, remove `param1` and `param2` from `@ARGV`.

```
my $param1 = shift;
my $param2 = shift;
```

Now you can process the piped output from `code1` using

```
while (<>) {
  ...;
}
```

A more general solution is to use [bash process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) as in

```
perl myperlscript.pl <(./other param1 param2) <(./code1 param1 param2 param3)
```

This makes the output of `other` and `code1` emerge from named pipes that

```
while (<>) {
  ...;
}
```

will happily process.

Answer (score -2):

There are two options for you.

1) read STDIN

```
while (<STDIN>) {
chomp();  
# do something again

}
```

2) Call the first program from your Perl script and process its output. See [recipe 16.05 in Perl Cookbook](http://books.perl.org/book/203).

```
open(PRG,"./code1 param1 param2 param3|") or die $!;
while (<PRG>) {
chomp();  
# do something again

}
```